# animate grow and radius at the same time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I made a simple animated [pie/donut chart](http://jsfiddle.net/uhhgnhs6/1/) with d3 and I was wondering if it would be possible to animate the radius and the grow at the same time.

As you can see from the example or the snippet below, only the grow is animated.

```js
const dataset = {
    apples: [{
        label: 'Category A',
        value: 53245,
  isSelected: true
    }, {
        label: 'Category B',
        value: 28479,
  isSelected: false
    }, {
        label: 'Category C',
        value: 24037,
  isSelected: false
    }, {
        label: 'Category D',
        value: 40245,
  isSelected: false
    }, {
        label: 'Category E',
        value: 30245,
  isSelected: false
    }],
    oranges: [{
        label: 'Category A',
        value: 200,
  isSelected: false
    }, {
        label: 'Category B',
        value: 200,
  isSelected: true
    }, {
        label: 'Category C',
        value: 200,
  isSelected: false
    }, {
        label: 'Category D',
        value: 200,
  isSelected: false
    }]
};


/**
 * Pie chart class
 */
function PieChart(options) {
    // Observable stream source
    this.selectionSource = new Rx.Subject();
    // Observable stream
    this.selection = this.selectionSource.asObservable();

    // Chart options/settings
    this.width = options.width;
    this.height = options.height;
    this.radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2;
    this.multiple = options.multiple;
 this.legend = options.legend;

    this.colorRange = d3.scale.category20();
 this.color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(this.colorRange.range());

    // Animation directions
    this.clockwise = {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 0
    };
    this.counterclock = {
        startAngle: Math.PI * 2,
        endAngle: Math.PI * 2
    };

    // Create the SVG on which the plot is painted.
    this.svg = d3.select(options.target)
        .append('svg:svg')
        .attr('width', this.width)
        .attr('height', this.height)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${this.width / 2}, ${this.height / 2})`);

    // Initial path creation.
    this.path = this.svg.selectAll('path');

    // Create the pie layout.
    this.pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d) {
            return d.value;
        })
        .sort(null);

    // Create arc functions.
    this.arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(this.radius - 100)
        .outerRadius(this.radius - 20);
    // Arc when a slice is selected/toggled on.
    this.arcSelected = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(this.radius - 90)
        .outerRadius(this.radius - 10);

    this.arcTween = arcTween;
    this.arcTweenOut = arcTweenOut;
    this.updateSelection = updateSelection;

    // Used by some of the functions that get a different context when called by d3.
    const thisRef = this;

    // Store the displayed angles in `current`.
    // Then, interpolate from `current` to the new angles.
    // During the transition, `current` is updated in-place by d3.interpolate.
    function arcTween(a) {
        const i = d3.interpolate(this.current, a);
        this.current = i(0);
        const slice = d3.select(this);
        return arcFn(slice, i);
    }

    function arcTweenOut() {
        const i = d3.interpolate(this.current, {
            startAngle: Math.PI * 2,
            endAngle: Math.PI * 2,
            value: 0
        });
        this.current = i(0);
        const slice = d3.select(this);
        return arcFn(slice, i);
    }

    function arcFn(slice, i) {
        return function(t) {
            if (slice.classed('selected')) {
                return thisRef.arcSelected(i(t));
            }
            return thisRef.arc(i(t));
        };
    }

    // NOTE: `this` will not be the class context,
    // but the contaxt set 
    function updateSelection(d) {
        const node = this;
        const slice = d3.select(node);
        const isToggled = slice.classed('selected');
        const event = {
            data: d.data
        };

        if (thisRef.multiple) {
            // Allow multiple slice toggling.
            toggle();
        } else {
            // Find previously selected slice.
            const selected = thisRef.svg.selectAll('path')
                .filter(function() {
                    return !this.isEqualNode(node) && d3.select(this).classed('selected');
                });

            // Deselect previous selection.
            if (!selected.empty()) {
                selected.classed('selected', false)
                    .transition()
                    .attr('d', thisRef.arc);
            }

            // Toggle current slice.
            toggle();
        }

        function toggle() {
            if (isToggled) {
                event.selected = false;
                slice.classed('selected', false)
                    .transition()
                    .attr('d', thisRef.arc)
                    .each('end', emit);
            } else {
                event.selected = true;
                slice.classed('selected', true)
                    .transition()
                    .attr('d', thisRef.arcSelected)
                    .each('end', emit);
            }
        }

        function emit() {
            thisRef.selectionSource.onNext(event);
        }
    }
}

PieChart.prototype.direction = function direction() {
    // Set the start and end angles to Math.PI * 2 so we can transition counterclockwise to the actual values later.
    let direction = this.counterclock;

    // Set the start and end angles to 0 so we can transition clockwise to the actual values later.
    if (!this.painted) {
        direction = this.clockwise;
    }

    return direction;
}

PieChart.prototype.update = function update(data) {
    const direction = this.direction();
    const thisRef = this;

    this.path = this.path
  .data(this.pie(data), function(d) {
   return d.data.label;
  })
  .classed('selected', selected.bind(this));
 
 function selected(datum) {
  return datum.data.isSelected;
 }

    // Append slices when data is added.
    this.path.enter()
        .append('svg:path')
        .attr('class', 'slice')
        .style('stroke', '#f3f5f6')
        .attr('stroke-width', 2)
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
            return thisRef.color(d.data.label);
        })
        .attr('d', this.arc(direction))
        // Store the initial values.
        .each(function(d) {
            this.current = {
                data: d.data,
                value: d.value,
                startAngle: direction.startAngle,
                endAngle: direction.endAngle
            };
        })
        .on('click', this.updateSelection);

    // Remove slices when data is removed.
    this.path.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(450)
        .attrTween('d', this.arcTweenOut)
        // Now remove the exiting arcs.
        .remove();

    // Redraw the arcs.
    this.path.transition()
        .duration(450)
        .attrTween('d', this.arcTween);

 // Add legend
 this.addLegend();
 
 // Everything is painted now,
 // we only do updates from this point on.
 if (!this.painted) {
  this.painted = true;
 }
}

PieChart.prototype.addLegend = function addLegend() {
 // The legend does not need to be repainted when we update the slices.
 if (this.painted || !this.legend) {
  return;
 }
 
 const thisRef = this;

 const rect = this.radius * 0.04;
 const spacing = this.radius * 0.02;
 
 const legend = this.svg.selectAll('.legend')
  .data(this.color.domain());
    
 legend.enter()
        .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'legend')
  .attr('fill-opacity', 0)
        .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
            const height = rect + spacing * 2;
            const offset =  height * thisRef.color.domain().length / 2;
            const horizontal = -4 * rect;
            const vertical = i * height - offset;
            return `translate(${horizontal}, ${vertical})`;
        });

    legend.append('rect')
        .attr('width', rect)
        .attr('height', rect)
        .style('fill', this.color);

    legend.append('text')
        .attr('x', rect + spacing)
        .attr('y', rect)
        .text(function(d) {
   return d;
  });
 
 legend.transition()
  .duration(450)
  .attr('fill-opacity', 1);
};



// DEMO/USAGE
const pieChart = new PieChart({
    target: '#chart',
 multiple: true,
 legend: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 400
});

console.log(pieChart);

pieChart.selection.subscribe(function(selection) {
    console.log(selection);
});


// Paint the plot.
pieChart.update(dataset.apples);

// This is only here for demo purposes
d3.selectAll("input")
    .on("change", update);

var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    d3.select("input[value=\"oranges\"]").property("checked", true).each(update);
}, 2000);

function update() {
    clearTimeout(timeout); // This is only here for demo purposes

    // Update the data.
    pieChart.update(dataset[this.value]);
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
}

form {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

// Graph
.slice {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.legend {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <form>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="dataset" value="apples" checked> Apples</label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="dataset" value="oranges"> Oranges</label>
    </form>

    <div id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle example showing how you can achieve that: https://jsfiddle.net/kmandov/9jrb1qLr/

[image]

I've used [Mike Bostock's pie chart example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) as a base, but you can adapt the code to your PieChart implementation.

The basic idea is that as soon as you switch category(`oranges/apples`), the pie arcs are recalculated to match the new data. The animation is done via a transition in the `change` function:

```
function change() {
    // ... calculate arcs
    path.transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTween(selected)); 
}
```

then the real magic is happening in the `arcTween` function. In the original example only the `start` and `end angles` are updated. You can store the target `outerRadius` and then update the `arc` generator on each step of the transition:

```
function arcTween(selected) {
    return function(target, i) {
      target.outerRadius = radius - (i === selected ? 0 : 20);
      var arcInterpolator = d3.interpolate(this._current, target);
      this._current = arcInterpolator(0);
      return function(t) {
        var interpolatedArc = arcInterpolator(t);
        arc.outerRadius(interpolatedArc.outerRadius);
        return arc(interpolatedArc);
      };
    }
}
```

Comment: That's possible to add custom event to update like "mouseover" ? On my graph there are gone if I update the piechart